# MySQL slave seems confused as to just how far out of date it is

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a slave that claims, in `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`, to be zero seconds behind the master.

However, it also says it's on Master_Log_File binlog.009636, which is 46.9 gig behind where the master is. I can look at the database and see the tables are all out of date.

No replication-related queries are running; the threads say "Waiting for master to send event" and "Has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it." Yet the log IS moving, as it's now 46.7 gig behind.

What is going on here? Server is MySQL 5.0.95.

Answer (score 1):

It means the thread has processed all events in the relay log files, and is now waiting for the I/O thread to write new events to the relay log.

Wait and watch whether size decreases as it seems to be updating because initially size was 46.9G and now it is 46.7G

Comment: The data is moving but so far as I can tell, no queries are running. And why does Seconds_Behind_Master report 0?

Comment: OK I think I know why it's not doing anything: It's moving a gigantic file over to load into the database and it's doing that very slowly. Still don't know why `Seconds_Behind_Master` reports 0.

Comment: I think you can find similar issue might be with v5.0.95 on http://bugs.mysql.com